# Apache Camel: save email to file (.eml) using routes

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am polling an email account, and that works great. I would like also to have a backup copy of the received messages as files (.eml). I have tried something like this:

```
from( mailurl+"?username="+username+"&password="+password+"&"+options)
.to( "file://backup?allowNullBody=false&forceWrites=true");
```

What I get is a file for every received email with a generated name like `ID-MACHINENAME-2443-1211718892437-1-0` in the desired directory, but the file is empty. I know I can make my own .eml file using a processor, but, isn't there a more straightforward way to do it using just routes? Why is the created file empty?

Comment: That should work, maybe try add a .log("${body}") before the .to() and make sure the email body is getting read

Comment: Thanks @stringy05. Doing so, the log is empty, but if I add a processor, I can access correctly the body and the attachments.

Comment: check the variables in which the body and attachment are showing up. It might be set in the body, must be coming as a property

Comment: There is no formal specifications around `eml` file format, though they mostly follow [RFC 0822](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822). Perhaps that's why there is no straight forward way to persist it. Body of the `IN` message should contain the email messages text body. Is your mail body empty by any chance? This  [test case](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-mail/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/mail/MailPollEnrichTest.java) may give you mode ideas.

Comment: @Josi in the processor are you simply doing .getIn().getBody()? I ask because that's basically exactly what happens with the ${body} expression. Or is it a multipart email with some tricky encoding?

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. I have made different tests and sometimes I get an empty body and sometimes not. I do not have a clear answer about that. I have found some other users complaining about that behavior. I think it is the way messages are composed, but this is only a guess. Anyway, what I need is not only to backup the body but the whole email, including attachments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found for making a backup copy of every incoming email to .eml file is creating a processor like this:

```
    public void process(Exchange ex) throws Exception {

    javax.mail.Message mailMessage = ex.getIn(org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailMessage.class).getMessage();

    File file = new File( "backupDirectory", "DesiredFileName.eml");
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));       
    mailMessage.writeTo(os);
    os.close();
}
```

This solution copies the whole message, including all headers, body and attachments.